# Ruby - reading numerated files

Tags: ruby, file

Imagine I have a bunch of files

```
a_1, a_2, ..., a_n
b_1, b_2, ..., b_n
```

and my script needs to read the files in the following order:

```
a_1, b_1, a_2, b_2, ..., a_n, b_n
```

I know how to read files when the name is specified. i.e. `File.open("a_1.txt", "r")`, but can I specify the name so that I have a loop that will just be something like

```
while i < n
   File.open("a_i.txt", "r")
   do sth
end
```

Comment: do you need something like  `File.open("a_#{i}.txt", "r")` ? while `i` will change, the file name will also change and you will be able to read new file on every new iteration. check this snippet - https://repl.it/HTfV

Comment: @marmeladze that will open `a_1.txt`, `a_2.txt`, `a_3.txt` and so on whereas the OP wants `a_1.txt`, `b_1.txt`, `a_2.txt`, `b_2.txt`, ...

Answer (score 3):

You could get the basename of the files, split around `_` and sort by `[number, letter]`:

```
# filenames = Dir.glob('input/*')
filenames = ["input/a_6", "input/b_8", "input/b_7", "input/a_3", "input/a_4", "input/b_4", "input/b_9", "input/b_1", "input/b_11", "input/a_11", "input/b_3", "input/b_2", "input/a_1", "input/b_6", "input/b_12", "input/a_8", "input/a_2", "input/a_9", "input/a_5", "input/b_10", "input/a_7", "input/b_5", "input/a_10", "input/a_12"]

filenames.sort_by! do |filename|
  letter, number = File.basename(filename).split('_')
  [number.to_i, letter]
end

p filenames
# ["input/a_1", "input/b_1", "input/a_2", "input/b_2", "input/a_3", "input/b_3", "input/a_4", "input/b_4", "input/a_5", "input/b_5", "input/a_6", "input/b_6", "input/a_7", "input/b_7", "input/a_8", "input/b_8", "input/a_9", "input/b_9", "input/a_10", "input/b_10", "input/a_11", "input/b_11", "input/a_12", "input/b_12"]
```

I usually like to put input files and scripts in different folders.

Finally, since `"3".to_i` and `"3.txt".to_i` both return `3`, this code should work with any extension (including no extension).

Comment: Note that there is a ".txt" extension in the OP's example.

Comment: @MarkThomas: Note that there's a `.txt` extension in half of OP's example :). Alors `"3.txt".to_i` is still `3`, so this code should work with any extension.

Comment: `to_i` doesn't really care, but if you want to be explicit about it: `File.basename(filename, '.txt')`

Comment: You're right! This works in that case. And it's very cleanly written. +1

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
file_names = (1..5).to_a.product(%w[a b]).map { |(a, b)| "#{b}_#{a}.txt" }

file_names.each do |file_name|
  # File.open(file_name, 'r')
end
```

Where `5` must be replaced with your `n`.

Or you might want to use nested loops:

```
(1..5).each do |n|
  %w[a b].each do |c|
    # File.open("#{c}_#{n}.txt", 'r')
  end
end
```

Comment: file can have `n` number and if some of file is missing it may cause an error, so better to fetch available files and sort them as per OP's requirement

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know in advance exactly what files are going to be there, you may want to sort a directory listing.

```
files = Dir["/path/to/files/*.txt"].sort_by{|f| [f[\d+].to_i, f]}
#=> ["a_1.txt", "b_1.txt", "a_2.txt", "b_2.txt", ...]
```

This sorts by the number in the filename then by the name itself. Then you just open them in array order.

Comment: You should probably sort by both, number and letter.

Comment: @Stefan that's a good point. `Dir` will sort them by ascii value, but I suppose it's not guaranteed that the sort_by will preserve that.

Comment: I have copied your first line in my answer ;)

Comment: @MarkThomas I don't think the order is guaranteed either, from the [docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Dir.html#method-c-glob): _"Note that case sensitivity depends on your system (so File::FNM_CASEFOLD is ignored), **as does the order** in which the results are returned."_

Comment: Edited to sort by number then name.

Answer (score 0):

```
 > files = Dir["/path/to/files/*.txt"]
 #=> ["a_5", "b_2", "b_9", "b_1", "b_10", "b_3", "b_5", "b_8", "a_1", "a_3", "a_8", "a_6", "a_2", "a_7", "b_6", "b_7", "b_4", "a_10", "a_4", "a_9"] 
 > files_in_order = files.group_by{|e| e.split("_").last.to_i}.sort.map{|v| v[1].sort}.flatten
 #=> ["a_1", "b_1", "a_2", "b_2", "a_3", "b_3", "a_4", "b_4", "a_5", "b_5", "a_6", "b_6", "a_7", "b_7", "a_8", "b_8", "a_9", "b_9", "a_10", "b_10"]
```

Comment: Your second answer only sorts by integer.

Answer (score 0):

Just out of curiosity, without explicit sorting:

```
Dir["/path/to/files/*.txt"].chunk { |e| e.split("_").first }
                           .map(&:last)
                           .reduce(&:zip)
                           .flatten
```

Comment: It doesn't sort the array, it removes some valid filenames and might introduce `nil`s. What's not to like? :)

Comment: @EricDuminil I am not sure I follow why anything is removed, but I believe, sorting is implicitly done by `Dir#[]`.

Comment: `%w(a_1 a_2 b_1 b_2 b_3)`

Comment: `Dir#[]`'s order depends on the underlying filesystem. You cannot expect it to return a sorted array.

Comment: I took `a_n, b_n` in the OP as the claim that sizes _must be_ equal. Also, there are no filesystems save for `ext4` (and `zfs` in some weird cases :)

Answer (score -1):

The code you need is:

```
while i < n
   File.open("a_#{i}.txt", "r") { |file|
      do sth
   }
end
```

In a string, when you put "#{expr}" inside, the value of expr will be evaluated and fill-in at runtime.
Example:

```
>irb
irb(main):001:0> i = 5
=> 5
irb(main):002:0> "a_#{i}"
=> "a_5"
```